# when user pick data from multipicker i need to push that object in array using id which selected from multipicker data comes from api

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks, react-query

when user pick  data from multipicker i need to push that object in array using id which selected from multipicker data comes from api

selectedReasons --> it's a state which has stored selected multipicker data
when user pick  data from multipicker i need to push that object in array using id which selected from multipicker data comes from api

selectedReasons --> it's a state which has stored selected multipicker data

```
import React, { Component, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, _Image, Alert } from "react-native";
import { Box, useToast } from "native-base";
import Spinner from "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay";
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from "react-native-keyboard-aware-scrollview";

import WizardItem from "./WizardItem";
import useGPSWizard from "hooks/useGPSWizard";
import { BRAND } from "config/constants";
import { Header, Toast } from "views/layout";
import { colors } from "config";
import styles from "./styles";
import {
  Button,
  MultiPicker,
  MultiPickerPlain,
} from "views/components/controls";
import useCommonData from "hooks/useCommonData";
import { scale } from "react-native-size-matters";
import { useFocusEffect } from "@react-navigation/native";

const AddGPSWizardLocation = ({ control }: any) => {
  const mappingFunction = (values: any) => {
    const selectedReasons: any = [];
    values.forEach((reason: any) => {
      if (reason?.isChecked === "false") {
        selectedReasons?.push(reason);
      }
    });
    setSelectedReasons(values);
    // setSelectedReasons(selectedRe asons);
  };
  const toast = useToast();
  const { commonData } = useCommonData();
  const { getGeofenceDetails, saveWizard, deleteWizardLocation, isLoading } =
    useGPSWizard();

  const [fencing, setFencing] = useState([]);
  const [initialSelectedReasons, setInitialSelectedReasons] = useState<any>([]);
  const [selectedReasons, setSelectedReasons] = useState<any>([]);

  console.log(initialSelectedReasons, "initialSelectedReasons........");
  console.log(selectedReasons, "selectedReasons.............");

  const loadSelectedReasons = (fencing: any) => {
    const selectedReasons =
      fencing && fencing.filter((reason: any) => reason.isChecked === "true");

    setSelectedReasons(selectedReasons);
    setInitialSelectedReasons(selectedReasons);
  };

  const fetchGeofenceDetails = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await getGeofenceDetails();
      console.log("hell", result, "hell");
      setFencing(result.data);
      loadSelectedReasons(result.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("...Error fetchGeofenceDetails", fetchGeofenceDetails);
    }
  };

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      fetchGeofenceDetails();
    }, [])
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (initialSelectedReasons.length != selectedReasons?.length) {
        Alert.alert(
          BRAND,
          "Before exiting this screen, be sure to save your GPS Risk Radar updates at the bottom of this screen."
        );
        return;
      }
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!fencing) return;

    loadSelectedReasons(fencing);
  }, [fencing]);
// for submitting records
  const submitSaveWizard = async (deselected?: any) => {
    const fences: any = [];

    // Check whether at least one wizard algorithm is selected
    selectedReasons?.forEach((reason: any) => {
      const tempReason = { ...reason };
      if (tempReason.isChecked === "true") {
        let isWizardSelected = "";
        tempReason.wizard?.forEach((wizardObj: any) => {
          if (wizardObj.isSelected === "true") {
            isWizardSelected = "true";
          }
        });
        tempReason.isWizardSelected = isWizardSelected;
        tempReason.isSelected = true;
        fences.push(tempReason);
      }
    });

    if (!deselected && !fences.length) {
      toast.show({
        render: () => (
          <Toast.Error text="Please select at least one treatment reason" />
        ),
      });
      return;
    }

    try {
      console.log("..saveFences", JSON.stringify(fences, null, 2));
      const result = await saveWizard({ fences });
      console.log("..result", result);
      toast.show({ render: () => <Toast.Success text={result.message} /> });
    } catch (error) {
      toast.show({
        render: () => <Toast.Error text="Error while saving wizard location" />,
      });
    }
  };

  // Close icon pressed on treatmentReason
  const deselectReason = (reason_id: any) => {
    const newSelectedReasons = selectedReasons?.map((reason: any) => {
      if (reason.reason_id === reason_id) {
        reason.isWizardSelected = "";
        reason.isSelected = "false";
        reason.isChecked = "false";
        reason.wizard?.forEach((r: any) => {
          r.isSelected = "false";
        });
      }
      return reason;
    });
    console.log("...deselect." + JSON.stringify(selectedReasons, null, 2));
    setSelectedReasons(newSelectedReasons);

    setTimeout(() => {
      submitSaveWizard(true);
    }, 700);
  };

  const reasonChangeHandler = (index: number, type: string, data: any) => {
    selectedReasons[index][type] = data;
    setSelectedReasons([...selectedReasons]);
  };

  const wizardObjChangeHandler = (
    index: number,
    wizardObjIndex: number,
    type: string,
    data: any
  ) => {
    selectedReasons[index].wizard[wizardObjIndex][type] = data;
    setSelectedReasons([...selectedReasons]);

    submitSaveWizard();
  };

  const detailObjChangeHandler = (
    index: number,
    detailObjIndex: number,
    type: string,
    data: any
  ) => {
    selectedReasons[index].wizard[detailObjIndex][type] = data;
    setSelectedReasons([...selectedReasons]);
  };

  const submitDeleteWizardLocation = async (geofence_id: any) => {
    Alert.alert("Confirm", "Are you sure you want to delete this location ?", [
      {
        text: "Cancel",
        style: "cancel",
      },
      {
        text: "Delete",
        onPress: async () => {
          try {
            const result = await deleteWizardLocation({ geofence_id });

            toast.show({
              render: () => <Toast.Success text={result.message} />,
            });

            await getGeofenceDetails();
          } catch (error) {
            toast.show({ render: () => <Toast.Error text={String(error)} /> });
          }
        },
      },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <Box style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Spinner color={colors.spinnerColor} size="large" visible={isLoading} />
      <Header title="Add GPS Risk Radar Locations" />
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        <View style={[styles.mainContainer, { flex: 1 }]}>
          <View style={[styles.mainContent, { padding: 20, flex: 1 }]}>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
              <MultiPickerPlain
                values={selectedReasons}
                onValueChange={mappingFunction}
                label="My Treatment Interests"
                headerText="My Treatment Interests"
                placeholder="Select up to 3 top areas that apply to you"
                options={commonData?.speciality_data?.map((option: any) => ({
                  value: String(option?.specialty_id),
                  label: String(option?.specialty_name),
                }))}
                labelStyle={{ fontSize: scale(16), fontWeight: "bold" }}
                maxLength={3}
                maxLengthAlert="Please select your TOP THREE interest areas for treatment."
              />

              <View style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
                {!isLoading &&
                  initialSelectedReasons &&
                  initialSelectedReasons?.length === 0 &&
                  selectedReasons &&
                  selectedReasons?.length === 0 && (
                    <Text
                      style={[
                        styles.danger_text,
                        { textAlign: "center", marginTop: 20 },
                      ]}
                    >
                      No Data Found
                    </Text>
                  )}
                {selectedReasons &&
                  selectedReasons?.map(
                    (treatmentReason: any, index: number) => {
                      console.log(
                        treatmentReason.reason_for_treatment,
                        "reasons........11"
                      );
                      if (treatmentReason?.isChecked === "false") return null;
                      console.log(
                        treatmentReason.reason_id,
                        "reasons........11"
                      );

                      return (
                        <WizardItem
                          key={treatmentReason?.reason_id}
                          index={index}
                          treatmentReason={treatmentReason}
                          // fencing={fencing}
                          deselectReason={deselectReason}
                          reasonChangeHandler={reasonChangeHandler}
                          wizardObjChangeHandler={wizardObjChangeHandler}
                          detailObjChangeHandler={detailObjChangeHandler}
                          deleteWizardLocation={submitDeleteWizardLocation}
                        />
                      );
                    }
                  )}
              </View>
              {selectedReasons?.length > 0 && (
                <View
                  style={{ paddingBottom: 15, paddingTop: 20, marginTop: 20 }}
                >
                  <Button onPress={() => submitSaveWizard()}>
                    Save Wizard Updates
                  </Button>
                </View>
              )}
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </Box>
  );
};
export default AddGPSWizardLocation;
```